# Second div element not select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the html structure:

```
<span id="17">yes here</span>
<div class="PricevariantModification vm-nodisplay"></div>
<div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
 <span class="a"></span>
 <span class="b"></span>
<div>
```

I need to select the span tag which class have "b" using the first one span

Anyone have know about it please give me proper answer.

Comment: `I need to select the span tag which class have "b" using the first one span` Why not targeting `.b` directly? What is the context of your question?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to use

You could use as transversal methods:

```
$('#17').nextAll('.PricesalesPrice:first').find('.b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below js code for your help

```js
var $span1 = $('span[id="17"]');

// $span1.parent().find().('span.b') <<-- next span having class b
alert($span1.parent().find('span.b'));
alert($span1.parent().find('span.b').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="17">yes here</span>
<div class="PricevariantModification vm-nodisplay"></div>
<div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
 <span class="a"></span>
 <span class="b">hello</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css next sibling  the [*Adjacent sibling selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
span.a + span.b{ color:red }
```

```html
<span id="17">yes here</span>
<div class="PricevariantModification vm-nodisplay"></div>
<div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
 <span class="a">Span a</span>
 <span class="b">Span b</span>
<div>
```

but the result is the same as

```css
span.b{ color:red }
```

```html
<span id="17">yes here</span>
<div class="PricevariantModification vm-nodisplay"></div>
<div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
 <span class="a">Span a</span>
 <span class="b">Span b</span>
<div>
```

or [jquery next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
$("span.a").next("span.b").css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="17">yes here</span>
 <div class="PricevariantModification vm-nodisplay"></div>
 <div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
    <span class="a">Span a</span>
    <span class="b">Span b</span>
 <div>
```